# Ios get contact Details from contact number

Tags: ios, contacts

Guys am working on a calling app for Ios,so naturally i have a dial-pad integrated.
The problem am facing in to get the contact details from number dialed from my dial-pad which i am showing in other screen.

Here is my code

```
+(PhoneContactModel*) getContactFrom:(NSString *)calledPhoneNumber{

    PhoneContactModel *contact=[[PhoneContactModel alloc]init];

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [AppUtils getCompatibleAdressBook];
    CFArrayRef all = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex n = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(all, i);

        ABMultiValueRef phones = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);


        for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
        {

            CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
            //CFRelease(phones);
            NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef;

            NSLog(@"apputil number %@",[AppUtils getNumberSanatized:phoneNumber]);

            if ([phoneNumber isEqualToString:calledPhoneNumber]){

                NSLog(@"apputil number matched %@",[AppUtils getNumberSanatized:phoneNumber]);
                contact.strFullName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
                contact.strFullName=[contact.strFullName stringByAppendingString:@" "];

                 if (lastName!=nil){
                contact.strFullName=[contact.strFullName stringByAppendingString:lastName];
                 }
                contact.imgContactImge=[AppUtils imageForContact:ref];
                contact.strNumber=phoneNumber;


                return contact;
            }

        }
    }

    contact.strFullName = calledPhoneNumber;
    return contact;
}
```

The problem appears like if i have a Contact A with number 64xxxx... and i dial +164xxxx.. from my dial-pad i don't get the contact details, Also you can see that in the method above i have to run a loop to find the matching contact even if there is a match, so is there a better method out there to do the same

Thanks

Comment: Instead of this You can use  //  if ([phoneNumber isEqualToString:calledPhoneNumber]){   //
NSString *string = @"hi bla bla";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain bla");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains bla!");
}
Also you can remove "+" if it exists in the string

Comment: ill try this dinesh, but dont you thing my approach may be slow or blocking since am using loop, Ain'there any other optimised method

Comment: one approach can be you save all your contacts in  your app using core data and then fetch using NSPredicate  But that will take some coding. This approach is also fine will not take any considerable time to make your app slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a better solution 
it can be seen here http://codesnight.blogspot.in/2013/11/ios-acces-contacts-from-number.html